# How to remove .Net core library projects from startup project drop-down (startup project candidates) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, csproj

I have migrated some of our project's csproj file from the old .Net framework format to the new .Net core format. As a result, all the migrated projects are shown in the startup project drop-down (same behavior in VS2017 and VS2019).

Ps: The drop-down is the one at the top part of VS with platform configuration at its left-hand-side and run button at its right-hand-side.

What I want:
Only show a project in the startup project candidate drop-down if its "OutputType" is executable.

Before the migration:
* Projects having "OutputType" being "Library" => not shown in drop-down
* Projects having "OutputType" being "WinExe" => shown in drop-down

After the migration:
* Projects having "OutputType" not set (default should be "Library") => shown in drop down
* Projects having "OutputType" being "Library" => shown in drop-down

To reproduce:
* Create "Class Library (.Net Framework)" project in VS => not shown in drop-down
* Create "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)" project in VS => shown in drop-down
* Create "Class Library (.Net Standard)" project in VS => shown in drop-down (WHY???)

Comment: Did you ever solve this yourself? It's very annoying!

Comment: Not yet.... my team decided to live with them...

Comment: It's so weird! I might actually try contacting Microsoft support. Will update if I get anywhere...

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/809530/new-style-csproj-class-library-projects-appear-in.html

Comment: Thank you for the MS post! Let's see what they say..